# Shopify javascript API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, shopify

I'm wondering what's the best strategy to create a custom product selection on shopify. We want to use backbone in order to create some drag and drop UI to select a product and add it to the cart.

I found that the API is mainly for admin tasks. Do you know if there's a javascript API?

Should I create a theme and add all the javascript logic there? or should I create a shopify app?

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes a drag drop UI with Backbone could be done without any trouble or special code.

Read http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API and you'll notice you can directly deal with a cart.

Basically, for you, just create your own theme. You can use Liquid to populate Backbone with data (namely Products)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shopping question per the FAQ =)

Here's a guide to doing it. Not sure what version it applies to.

http://superdit.com/2011/04/02/drag-drop-shopping-cart-using-jquery/